# Cartoon series from the 90's

Tags: story-identification, space, cartoon

A family of four, dad, mom, son, daughter and their two strange pets are traveling through space in search of strange new worlds.

Comment: What did they look like?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This isn't much information for folks to go on.  Can you provide more details ?  Ex - were the children young ( say <= 12 ) or were they teens.  How about the pets, can you give us any kind of description / characteristics ?  Where was this watched, US, Canada, UK, other ?

Comment: I really like Mézga family, but the family were not traveling through space together. In the first series they (Aladár, the son) contacted a descendant from the 30th century, in the second series there were space travel (but only Aladár and the dog). In the third the family (+1 neighbor) traveled together but "only" around the world.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are talking about the Mezga Family an hungarian cartoon. Different names in different languages, but check the series here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_M%C3%A9zga_Family

check this italian website for some pics: http://www.anni80.info/cartoni/mezzil.html

Comment: I don't remember the Mézga family having 2 strange pets.

Comment: But they do. A strange cat and a strange dog.

Comment: @sputnik21 Was this the cartoon you meant. I loved it when I was young. :)

Answer (score 3):

The cartoon that immediately came to my mind is "Les Mondes Engloutis" (English: "Spartakus and the Sun Beneath the Sea", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartakus_and_the_Sun_Beneath_the_Sea).

The story is about a weird girl, a man with a cool bracer, 2 kids and 2 strange, tatoo like pets travelling on a rubber duck-shaped spaceship-like vessel called ShagShag from their city located inside the planetary crust of the Earth towards the surface with the goal to save their artificial sun from dying.

Comment: This is great!! Thank you so much! Code Twice got it right; it's "Les Mondes Engloutis". I used to watch it on hungarian tv in the late 80's and even thou i didn't understand hungarian, (i am romanian) i was a fan of this cartoon. I still find my self humming the soundtrack. This series was really inspiring to me as a child. Thanks for your time! Enjoy!    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-IiD_JHLo8

Comment: Glad I could help! I guess we have been watching the show on the same TV channel then :) Can you accept my response then so that the question is solved?